# Allow Google News to index your site

Tags: indexing, google-news

A few days ago i found a website with somekinda seal. When i clicked on that seal i went to somekinda website, that says `The webpage you just visited allows google news to index their website` or something. Does someone of you knows that site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google News chooses which sites they want to index.

You can suggest a web site [here](http://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=191208&rd=1).

What you found was a page developed by the web site themselves.  Their site may or may not be indexed by Google News.